# How to jump out the current while loop and run the next loop whenever meeting a certain condition?

Tags: python

The Python script that I am using is not exactly as below, but I just want to show the logic. Let me explain what I am trying to do: I have a database, and I want to fetch one population (a number `A`) a time from the database until all numbers are fetched. Each time fetching a number, it does some calculations (`A` to `B`) and store the result in `C`. After all fetched, the database will be updated with `C`. The `while` `condition` just works like a 'switch'.

The thing is that I don't want to fetch a negative number, so when it does fetch one, I want to immediately jump out the current loop and get a next number, until it is not a negative number. I am a beginner of Python. The following script is what I could write, but clearly it doesn't work. I think something like `continue`, `break` or `try`+`except` should be used here, but I have no idea.

```
for _ in range(db_size):
    condition = True     
    while condition:
        # Get a number from the database
        A = db.get_new_number()
        # Regenerate a new number if A is negative 
        if A < 0:
            A = db.get_new_number()
        B = myfunc1(A)
        if B is None:
            continue
        C=myfunc2(B)
db.update(C)
```

Comment: For "if B is None part: continue", this part doesn't matter. The problem is only for A, not B or C.

Comment: Just replace `if` with `while`. When the inner loop exits, `A` is guaranteed to be non-positive. The question then is just whether the inner loop *ever* terminates.

Comment: @chepner to fix that issue, you would just add a secondary condition, e.g `if A < 0 or db.is_out_of_numbers():`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop that repeats until the condition is met.

```
for _ in range(db_size):
    condition = True     
    while condition:
        # Get a number from the database
        while True:
            A = db.get_new_number()
            if A is None:
                raise Exception("Ran out of numbers!")
            # Regenerate a new number if A is negative 
            if A >= 0:
                break
        B = myfunc1(A)
        if B is None:
            continue
        C=myfunc2(B)
db.update(C)
```

My code assumes that `db.get_new_number()` returns `None` when it runs out. Another possibility would be for it to raise an exception itself, then you don't need that check here.